# Complex conditional column when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have here two tables: `Customer` and `Company` in One-To-One relationship. In other words, `Company` table has a PK `customerid` column which is a foreign key that references to the PK `id` of Customer. This means, that if there's a record in the `Company` table, then the corresponding customer is a company.

The following is a **simplified** visual diagram:

[image]

Now, when you want to find out how many customers and companies there are in both tables per letter (representing the customer name or the company name), you can execute the following query:

```
SELECT LEFT(u.name, 1) AS letter, count(*) AS count FROM 
    (
        SELECT name,
            CASE
                WHEN (SELECT customerid FROM company WHERE company.customerid = id) THEN "Company"
                ELSE "Customer"
            END
            AS origin
        FROM customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT companyname AS name, 'Company' AS origin FROM company
    ) AS u
GROUP BY letter
ORDER BY letter
```

Then you get the following result set:

[image]

However, I still need one more generated column in my result set (e.g. column 'type`), where I can see if there are only customers representing the corresponding letter, or companies, or both.

This means: I need something like this as a result set:

```
letter | count | type
--------------------------
A        1       Companies
B        3       Both
C        2       Customers
<...>
```

Is it possible to do it by implementing a conditional column? I have already tried so many different things; it just fails every time.

---

**JUST IN CASE**

Just in case you need this simplified SQL-seed:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

-- Table structure for table `company`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `customerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `companyname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_company$customerid` FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

-- Dumping data for table `company`
LOCK TABLES `company` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `company` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `company` VALUES (2,'Jane Solutions LLC'),(4,'Disney Company'),(5,'Bad Company');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `company` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

-- Table structure for table `customer`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pseudonym` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

-- Dumping data for table `customer`
LOCK TABLES `customer` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customer` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (1,'John Smith','John (NY)'),(2,'Jane Smith',NULL),(3,'John Smith','John (LA)'),(4,'Tom Smith',NULL),(5,'Alice Smith',NULL),(6,'Bob Smith',NULL),(7,'Benoit Smith',NULL),(8,'Craig Smith',NULL),(9,'Celine Smith',NULL);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customer` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

Comment: This isn't one to one, it's many to one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's one-to-one The FK is the PK (bonkers as it may seem)

Comment: One company cannot have many customers (cannot reference to many customers, as FK customerid is a PK). So this is One-To-One. However, some EER Diagram generators (like, for instance Reverse Engineer of Workbench) will show the relation as One-To-Many, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation over your computed `origin` column to do the check:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(u.name, 1) AS letter,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN origin = 'Company' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
              COUNT(CASE WHEN origin = 'Customer' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Both'
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN origin = 'Company' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Companies'
         WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN origin = 'Customer' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN 'Customers' END AS type
FROM 
(
    SELECT name, 'Customer' AS origin FROM customer
    UNION ALL
    SELECT companyname, 'Company'     FROM company
) t
GROUP BY letter
ORDER BY letter;
```

Comment: There was a bug in your code. I tried to edit it. But it were not applied. It's u instead of t or vice verca... because on one place you have `u`, on the other place `t`... Anyway. Thank you....